# How to call web-service in web browser?

Tags: ionic-framework

**This API syntax is working on mobile app but on ionic serve it dosent works on web browser**

```
let body = JSON.stringify({ "Id": Id });
let headers = new Headers({ 'Content-Type': 'application/json' });
return this.http.post(url, body, { headers: headers })
  .map(res => res.json())
  .catch(this.handleError);
```

Comment: which ionic version is to used

Comment: Please post the your error from your console

Comment: Please look in this http://blog.ionic.io/handling-cors-issues-in-ionic/